# Worklight: How to verify if JSONStore is storing the data securely

Tags: windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing a hybrid mobile app using worklight 6.0 for Android, iOS and Windows8 platforms. We wanted to securely store the user password on the device for offline use. To accomplish that, we are using JSONStore object. Worklight document says - JSONStore is not supported on windows platform. But I can initialize, add and retrieve data from JSONStore on windows8 machine. How I can verify, if the data is getting stored securely on the device using JSONStore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per the user documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_features.html), JSONStore is not supported in Windows 8.

What you may be experiencing is its *dev support* while *previewing* the applicaton in Windows 8.
This is very much not the same as supporting it.

From the user documentation:

> Note: 1. Dev Only means designed only for development, with no
>   security features and a ~5 MB storage space limit.

So, JSONStore does not support Windows 8.
Thus, this question is invalid...